# Android Studio : Cant Debug with USB after Setting to Bluestack

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, usb

I got an error while debugging with USB Debug 
"USB Device Not Found".
but i can debug with BlueStack. cuz i set adb into localhost:5555 
does it affect the procces for my USB debugging.

Comment: "cuz" ? If you haven't tried anything yourself this is too broad for anyone to answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you already install a correct driver for your device.
If still have problem, try kill the adb.exe process from task manager and then klik run again..